# is it possible to redirect 301 from one blogspot (google) blog to another blogspot (google) blog?

Tags: blogger

Is it possible to redirect 301 from one blogspot (google) blog to another blogspot (google) blog? if yes kindly show me the simple procedure, as I don't want to redirect it using java script and others, so kindly guide me the way for 301 redirect from one blogspot to another. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code after "head" tag. you must replace [www.sebahotnews.org](http://www.sebahotnews.org) with your another BlogSpot site URL.

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='https://www.sebahotnews.org/'" />
```